# How to calculate new value for field in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I've got a few problems with a database I have created.

- I want to calculate a Total Price (Sandwich Quantity multiplied by Sandwich Price). I had it working before, but I had to delete Sandwich Price from the OrderDetailsT table of which it was originally in. I'm now having issues with this calculation, as I cannot make a calculation in the OrderDetailsT table (Sandwich Price isn't there).

  - How can I apply the Discount to the Total Price if the Total Price is more than $50 for instance? After the Discount has been applied to the Total Price field, I would also like to store it in the NewPriceAfterDiscount field.

Here is an image detailing my situation:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple questions in one:
But, first of all. As the image shows, why do you have a left join between OrderDetails an Sandwich? In a order calculation you don't need not ordered sandwiches.

To total price calculation:
Add a new column to the query grid (assuming discount is a percentaje stored has a number between 0 and 1):

```
[SandwichT].[SandwichPrice] * [OrderDetailT].[SandwichQuantity] * [OrderDetailT].[Discount]
```

To store total price: you can use the above formula, but using a update query.
If you plan to show the prices in a form or in a report:

- you can do de calculations on the fly (and don't store the total
  price)
- or you should update the total price un one query and then build another
  query as datasource of the form/report.
- another posibility (my recomendation) is to store the total in the input form